# Where can I find database scripts for the version 2.3.0 version? Unable to find it under the 2.3.0 kit

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I am new to quartz. I am unable to find the database scripts under docs  folder in  quartz-2.3.0-distribution.tar.gz . There are only images under docs folder. But it is available under docs folder in  quartz-2.2.3-distribution.tar.gz version.  Where can I find database scripts for 2.3.0 version? Should the same be used as in 2.2.3 version?  Also where can I find the migration database scripts. Kindly help.The official link http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-core/src/main/resources/org/quartz/impl/jdbcjobstore is under maintenance(rework is going on).
Kindly help.

Comment: This is the place for the sql scripts  quartz-2.2.3-distribution.tar\quartz-2.2.3-distribution\quartz-2.2.3\docs\dbTables

Answer (score 6):

See issue https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz/issues/414 which acknowledge missing the `docs/dbTables` in the distribution file.

For until it get fixed you can navigate to https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz/tree/quartz-2.3.x/quartz-core/src/main/resources/org/quartz/impl/jdbcjobstore (branch 2.3.x) for finding the SQL scripts.

Found via https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz/wiki/How-to-Setup-Databases#first-time-postgresql-server-setup